# Effect of treatment in a model with random effects

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, treatment-effect, intercept

I am working with Eyes (volume), each person has two eyes and I am using random effects to account for this in my model. (linear mixed effects model)

The problem with nlme is that the output needs always to be interpreted against a reference value. You can "delete" the reference by deleting the intercept (0+), but when you use an interaction model, as in this case to assess the effect of treatments in the different groups, the interaction output still gets referenced. (see output below)

```
mod1.lme <- lme(volume ~ 0+ Group * Treatment, random= ~1|ID, data = df, na.action = na.omit)


Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: df 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  584.8247 597.5875 -286.4124

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | ID
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev: 0.001383396 21.78922

Fixed effects: volume ~ 0+ Group * Treatment
                          Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
Group1                 71.72603  8.263708 35  8.679642  0.0000
Group2                 80.03025  4.906773 35 16.310158  0.0000
Treatment              -4.07192  4.597503 28 -0.885680  0.3833
Group2:Treatment       -2.69588  5.035967 28 -0.535324  0.5967
 Correlation: 
                       Gr1     Grp2   Trt
Group2                0.000              
Treatment            -0.856  0.000       
Group2:Treatment      0.781 -0.291 -0.913

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.8657899 -0.7139400 -0.1747370  0.9796536  1.9893271 

Number of Observations: 66
Number of Groups: 37
```

I am not so sure if this is the correct model to assess the effect of treatment accounting for inter eye correlation (so the fact that for example, the left eye can be in group 1 and right eye can be in group 2, or maybe both left and right eye are in group 1 for example)

I would be super grateful if you could give me a hand with this.

Thank you very much in advance,

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should look like the following:

```
lme(volume ~ 0 + Group + Group:Treatment, ...)
```

with `...` being the rest of the stuff in your model. The results will be four coefficients, one for `Group1` and one for `Group2`, which represent the volume in the control group for each group, and one for `Group1:Treatment` and one for `Group2:Treatment`, which represent the treatment effect in each of the groups. With this syntax, you can't directly test whether the baseline volume or treatment effect differ between the two groups.

Comment: Amazing! it works, Thanks!!! :)